# Can we get optimal values when we calculate the optimal problem every time?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis, convex-optimization

I am writing a code of the optimization in a [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1805.08898.pdf).

However, I found that I get a "Inf" for optimal value of this formula below sometimes, so I want to ask, can we get optimal values when we calculate the optimal problem every time? I think we can, but I can't prove this to myself. Does anyone know the explanation?

\begin{array}{rl}
\min_{F_k,\rho_k}&\sum_{k=1}^K tr(\mathbf F_k)\\
\text{s.t.}& 0\le\rho_k\le1\\
&\frac{\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_k \mathbf h_k}{\bar {r_{k}}}-\sum\limits_{j \neq k}\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_j \mathbf h_k \ge \sigma^2_{a_k}+\frac{\sigma^2_{d_k}}{\rho_k}\\
&\mathbf F_k\succeq0\\
&\sum\limits_{j=1}^{K}\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_j \mathbf h_k + \sigma^2_{a_k} \ge \frac{\hat P}{1-\rho_k}
\end{array}

1. $\rho_k$ is a power fraction,deciding how much percent of power do the energy harvest,how much percent do information decoding.
2. $\mathbf h_k$ is a complex circularly symmetric gaussian channel, $CN(0,0.0018)$, as we know, it is random value,every $\mathbf h_k$ is $4$ by $1$ matrix.
3. $\mathbf F $ is $\mathbf f \mathbf f^H$, and $\mathbf f$ is beamforming, every $\mathbf f$ is $4$ by $1$ matrix.
4. $\bar {r_k}$ is a SINR value, in here,we set it is 10dB.
5. $\hat P$ is like a harvested value,but it will change every time when we calculate the optimal value.
6. $\sigma^2_{d_k}$ and $\sigma^2_{a_k}$ are a noise variance when we are decoding and harvesting energy, they are $-50$dBm and $-70$dBm, is a constant value, not a random I think.

In the code , I write the second and fourth set of constraints as below, in order to obey the DCP rules,or the code can't run

$$\Re\bigg(\frac{\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_k \mathbf h_k}{\bar {r_{k}}}-\sum\limits_{j \neq k}\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_j \mathbf h_k\bigg) \ge \sigma^2_{a_k}+\frac{\sigma^2_{d_k}}{\rho_k}$$

$$\Re\bigg(\sum\limits_{j=1}^{K}\mathbf h_k^H \mathbf F_j \mathbf h_k + \sigma^2_{a_k}\bigg) \ge \frac{\hat P}{1-\rho_k}$$

Comment: Section IV.C of the paper you reference discusses conditions under which the problem you wish to solve is feasible. Have you checked for feasibility before you solve?

Comment: @DavidM. IV.C  is for OP and OP1,however my problem is OP4.The result of OP4 is infeasible sometimes,but also feasible sometimes,i am also confused why

Comment: Are you applying the $\Re$ operator to combat numerical effects that lead to remaining complex terms? (I would not say that is related to DCP, that's just cleaning).  The easiest way to analyze infeasibility is to add non-negative slack variable and then minimize these, to see how far from zero they can be.

Comment: ...and why aren't you simply solving this simple problem as an linear SDP?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg I use the cvx to solve it.if i don't add "real" to the left hand formula,the window will show me "{complex affine} >= {convex}",and the cvx will stop running at once.How do rewrite the formula if i don't use the "real" to the left hand in the cvx?

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Can you show me how to solve this in linear SDP ? Because in cvx,i just write the formula in it,and obey the DCP rule.By the way ,the paper also said,the OP4 satisfies the DCP rule,so it can efficiently compute it

Comment: The constraint is real in theory, bu as I guessed, you have to add real to clean away remaining numerical noise causing it to have some complex terms. It is converted to a linear SDP by performing a Schur complement over $\rho$ and $1-\rho$, but I guess you've already done that as you are using cvx. As I said, add slacks to analyze what is causing infeasibility

Comment: @JohanLöfberg What does the slacks,you said, mean? I had discussed it with someone in the cvx website,he said maybe the reason is $\mathbf h$,because  $\mathbf h$ is random,so it cause the optimal problem become infeasibility sometimes,but  i think $\mathbf h$ is a gaussian channel,gaussian channel is  a random,so i can't assume it is a constant.

Comment: @JohanLöfberg here is the cvx website i ask,and the discussion with someone : http://ask.cvxr.com/t/why-does-the-optimal-value-become-nan-sometimes/6035

Comment: As I said, if you encounter infeasibility when you don't expect infeasibility, you have to debug that. Your question is not about being sdp or not (obviously you have already implemented an LMI, otherwise cvx wouldn't get started). A common way to do that is by adding slack variables in the constraints, and minimizing them, to see which are non-negative which indicates a problematic constraint

Comment: Adding slacks means that if you think $f_i(x)\leq 0$ should be feasible, you solve the problem $f_i(x)\leq s_i, s_i \geq 0$ and then minimize $\sum s_i$, for example. An infeasible constraint will force $s_i$ to be positive, and thus you have a pointer to look deeper to find an error in the code, or understand why it could become infeasible.

Comment: BTW, in your code you have an operation of the form cat(2,x). That operation does nothing according to MATLAB syntax. x = randn(2,3,4);isequal(x,cat(2,x)) returns true

Comment: @JohanLöfberg wait,we didn't discuss the question i ask.so Can we get optimal values when we calculate the optimal problem every time?

Comment: If you mean if it is feasible for any $h$, no. Simple counter example is $h=0$

Comment: @JohanLöfberg Do you mean sometimes the answer will give me feasible,but NaN for optimal value or infeasible and NaN for optimal value?

Comment: When the problem is infeasible there is nothing to return, hence NaN is returned instead.

Comment: but sometimes the window will show me feasible,can i just ignore the infeasible,and say sometime we can't find the optimal value for optimal problem?

Comment: oh no,it should be Inf,not NaN